Can't properly close pdfium PDF before using shutil to move it
I am using pypdfium2 to read text from a PDF and then later move it to a different folder, but I am getting the same error telling me that it is open and can't be moved.
How do I properly close the document for it to be moved? I added the True parameter for autoclose but no change.
I will add that stopping my program still means I can't move the file around in file explorer. I need to close out of Spyder entirely before I can move these files around.
import time
import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers
import shutil
import pypdfium2 as pdfium
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter


class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=['*.pdf'],
                                                             ignore_directories=True, case_sensitive=False)
     
    def id_parsing(self, path, index):
        id = ""
        pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(path, "", True)
        try:
            page = pdf[index].get_textpage()
            if (str(page.search("A285").get_next()) != "None"):
                x = page.search("A285").get_next()[0]
                idArr = page.get_text_bounded()[x+31:x+43].split()
                id = str(max(idArr, key=len))
        except Exception:
            id = "-1"
        return id
   
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("Watchdog received created event - %s." %event.src_path)
        reader = PdfReader(event.src_path)

        lastId = "";
        id = ""
        startIndex = 0;

        for i in range(len(reader.pages)  + 1):
            id = self.id_parsing(event.src_path, i)
            if (id == ""):
                id = lastId
            print("ID:" + id)
                
            if (id != lastId and lastId != ""):
                writer = PdfWriter()
                outputPdf = lastId + '.pdf'
                for page in range(startIndex, i):
                    writer.add_page(reader.pages[page])
                    with open(outputPdf, "wb") as f:
                        writer.write(f)
                startIndex = i
                source = r'C:\Users\jkaplan\.spyder-py3'
                dest = r'C:\Users\jkaplan\Documents\Test\Processed Files'
                shutil.move(source + '\\' + outputPdf, dest)
                
            lastId = id
            
        dest2 = r'C:\Users\jkaplan\Documents\Test\Completed'
        #shutil.move(event.src_path, dest2)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_path = r"C:\Users\jkaplan\Documents\Test"
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive = False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(15)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print("Observer Stopped")
        
    observer.join()

I tried using a with(open) statement but I got errors with pdfium and it didn't make any difference.
